# Are there other countries besides Türkiye that insist their name be written in English using diacritics (or even other letters) not common in English?

Tags: comparative-politics, public-relations

Regarding Türkiye's campaign to have their name changed (from Turkey) in foreign languages, it struck me as a bit unusual to insist on the umlaut-ed ü, since English doesn't normally have that diacritic. So, is this an uncommon insistence, or are there other countries that insist on having some uncommon (in English) letters or diacritics, in English communications regarding the country's name?

---

As someone asked for a quote, one of the ironies is that state broadcaster TRT [spells it](https://www.trtworld.com/magazine/why-turkey-is-now-turkiye-and-why-that-matters-52602) without umlaut sometimes [in English articles], but they also quote an official note saying that:

> The vast majority of people in Turkiye feel that calling the country by its local variation only makes sense and is in keeping with the country's aims of determining how others should identify it.
>
> In a nod to that, the recently published communique was clear that "within the scope of strengthening the 'Turkiye' brand, in all kinds of activities and correspondence, especially in official relations with other states and international institutions and organisations, necessary sensitivity will be shown on the use of the phrase 'Türkiye' instead of phrases such as 'Turkey,' 'Turkei,' 'Turquie' etc."

Comment: Can you please quote the actual insistence?

Comment: @Greendrake: Well, the funny part is that the US agreed to change the spelling but not how it's read, which was actually the main Turkish complaint... "[US] Officials later confirmed the spelling change, but said the pronunciation would stay the same." https://www.dw.com/en/us-officially-changes-spelling-of-turkey-to-turkiye/a-64301304
 [continues]

Comment: Whereas 
"State broadcaster TRT [...] pointed out the Cambridge English Dictionary's definition of one of the meanings of the word as "something that fails badly" or "a stupid or silly person". [...] The Ü may be tricky for most of the international audience who don't have that letter in their alphabet but it's the same as the German Ü, like the U in pure or cue. So for an English-speaker, changing the first vowel of Turkey to a Ü and adding an E to the end (as in pet) is enough to pronounce the new name perfectly."
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61671913

Comment: The quoted text isn't evidence that the Turkish government is insisting on the diacritic. It's evidence that they are insisting on Türkiye over "'Turkey,' 'Turkei,' 'Turquie'", but it's not evidence they're insisting on Türkiye over Turkiye. Perhaps they insist on that too, but it seems the ordinary letters is what that quote is about. In fact, the fact TRT freely moves between the diacritic and non-diacritic versions is evidence that that isn't the complaint, rather than it being "ironic".

Comment: @Fizz: *“[…] but it's the same as the German Ü, like the U in pure or cue. […]* – Not your mistake, but that certainly is not correct for German and also not for Turkish as far as I can tell from a quick look at phonetic notation. The *u* in *pure* or *cue* is pronounced /jɔː/ or similar while the German *ü* is either /yː/ or /ʏ/.

Comment: @Schmuddi in fact the vowel in [pure](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pure#Pronunciation) is not the same as that in [cue](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cue#Pronunciation).  What you say is true of _cue_ but not of _pure;_ Wrzlprmft's comment is true of _pure_ (but only for some non-rhotic accents) but not of _cue._

Comment: @phoog: Fair enough. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On the UN [list of countries](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/member-states), **Côte d’Ivoire** is the only other country to use a “special” character. From Wikipedia:

> in April 1986, the government declared that Côte d'Ivoire (or, more fully, *République de Côte d'Ivoire*) would be its formal name for the purposes of diplomatic protocol and has since officially refused to recognize any translations from French to other languages in its international dealings. Despite the Ivorian government's request, the English translation "Ivory Coast" (often "the Ivory Coast") is still frequently used in English by various media outlets and publications.

Elsewhere [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_by_continent), [2](https://www.state.gov/countries-areas/sao-tome-and-principe/)], São Tomé and Príncipe is often spelled with its diacritics, however, the UN spells it “Sao Tome and Principe.” Its name is Portuguese.

Across the world, [Åland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85land) (a Swedish-speaking dependency of Finland) and [Curaçao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cura%C3%A7ao) (a constituent country of the Kingdom of the Netherlands) are commonly spelled with their special characters. I haven't yet looked for the UN official list of dependencies.

Comment: then again, Sao Tome is often written either just as that or "Sao Tome et Principe"

Comment: @jwenting I have never seen that. Why would you use a French (or Latin, I suppose) word in the middle of a Portuguese name?

Comment: @jwenting Did you mean "e Principe"?

Comment: @Fatalize: I think more important is that seeing the accent over o you know it's spelled/rendered with accents, so the missing accent over e distinguishes the pronunciation from côté (a super common word). There are even semi-intentional word games like https://www.criterionchannel.com/du-cote-de-la-cote

Comment: OTOH he difference in pronunciation between  /kɔt/ (cote) and /kot/ (côte) is rather more subtle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JDA3r4dQwE

Comment: Interestingly, but surely rather obscure, diaresis rather than umlaut "is also used officially in the name of the island [Teän](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te%C3%A4n)" (visually looks the same, but pronunciation rule is different)

Comment: @Fizz Well, you're the one that asked about countries, not uninhabited islets.

Comment: Sure, but you've included dependencies too :-) Of course Teän has a pop of zero, so it's not even that. But it is part of the UK.

Comment: By some definitions, Côte d'Ivoire has *two* special characters, as the apostrophe isn't part of the English/Latin alphabet! Of course defining "special" as non-ASCII masks this problem.

Comment: @ChrisH Not sure apostrophes are really "special" characters, but if they are, there's one other UN state that uses one: "Lao People's Democratic Republic" is the official full name of Laos.  By the same token, Timor-Leste (a.k.a. East Timor) is the only UN member to include a hyphen in the name.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I knew it wouldn't be the only country to use a non-letter in the name.  Part of the inspiration for the comment was the discussion under the question about what constitutes an acceptable letter in English

Comment: I do not think that apostrophes and hyphens are special enough to be an answer to this question, but feel free to add an answer.

Comment: When I saw "Sao Tome et Principe" in a comment, I though of French, but it seems French will at least keep the **é** and may use hyphens, so the country can be called "Sao Tomé-et-Principe" in French (along with other variants). Of course, French is not super relevant in a discussion in English about a country whose main language is Portuguese, even if French is a "world language".

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes, my bad :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want to extend the country aspect to Canadian native nations, yes, that is very much a thing these days.  Here's some for BC

- Sḵwx̱wú7mesh Úxwumixw - Squamish Nation
- xʷməθkʷəy̓əm - Musqueam
- etc...

What's a bit unexpected, when I last looked at it is that:

- Some (all?) of these are symbols that are mostly (all?) coming from the [international phonetic alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).
- There is limited homogenization between tribes with similar languages.  Other tribes have yet different symbols.  Some have the intent to develop a system which can be entered in text editors and computers.  Some don't.
- There is very limited communication - to the rest of us - in how they are supposed to be pronounced.  Since they aren't homogenized, it is quite possible different bands would struggle to communicate.
- On the other hand, if they are primarily from the IPA, using phonetic spelling may be very helpful to preserve pronunciation - some languages have very few speakers left.

The first I was exposed to native names was when I lived in Florida.  Tallahassee, Okeechobee, etc...  Now, I fully expect that the pronunciation by the average non-native Floridan was atrocious.  But it was nice that people did use those names and they could work on the pronunciation from the basic English.

I have no idea what `7` does phonetically so that doesn't work here.  We have road signs that no one has a clue how to pronounce, aside from tribal members.

More info from [First Peoples Cultural Council](https://fpcc.ca/resource/orthographies/):

> Linguistic orthographies are based on the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA), the alphabet used by linguists to uniquely represent the sounds of the world’s languages.
>
> Many B.C. languages have relatively *newly developed practical alphabets* which differ significantly from the orthography commonly used by linguists. As they have developed independently, *these practical alphabets may differ from each other as to which symbol is used to represent which sound*.
>
> ...
>
> Assuming a community wants a writing system, there are many things to be considered in choosing an appropriate one. An interesting example of different choices in orthography development is that of Hul’q’umi’num’ and Hən̓q̓əm̓inəm̓, *two sister dialects* of a Salish language of southwestern B.C.
>
> The Quw’utsun’ Hul’q’umi’num’ of Vancouver Island have chosen a practical alphabet which uses only letters found on an English keyboard, plus the apostrophe. This ensures that their language can be written, typed, and used in email with ease. In contrast, the speakers of χʷmθk̓ʷiʔəm Hən̓q̓əm̓inəm̓, whose traditional territory occupied what is now much of Greater Vancouver, have chosen a linguistic alphabet which emphasizes the distinctness of their language’s sounds. These two alphabets look very different, but both represent the sounds of the language accurately and systematically.

(Note:  the use of *tribe* may feel a bit odd, but those are terms used here, along with *band* and *nation*).

Comment: This is a bit of a rant but, FYI "7" is a glottal stop, at least among the Salish languages.

Comment: How is it a rant?  Do we actually know how to pronounce this in general?  We don't.  And since it is not unified, it'll be very hard to sign up anyone to learn them.  Again, read what I said about Tallahassee - I think it is an excellent idea to use native names.

Comment: but you are welcome to make suggestions to make this less ranty

Comment: 7 is most likely a reverse-to-ASCII of ʔ (glottal stop) from IPA. In fact, the wiki article on the latter even has a BC road sign as example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bilingual_road_sign_in_squamish_language_2.jpg But the latter is clearly bilingual, there's no indication "7" is in the English spelling.

Comment: But these are examples of how they refer to themselves. For example, Germany refers to itself as "Deutschland" yet many other countries use their own translations. No one will refer to the Squamish as "Sḵwx̱wú7mesh Úxwumixw" unless actually speaking their language.

Comment: How to pronounce Kansas vs how to pronounce Arkansas? And then there's the whole "gh" thing. The "nice" thing about English is that pronunciation has no hard and fast rules. English is unlike Spanish, where the word as spelled generally gives clues regarding how to pronounce it.

Comment: What's your basis for your statement that "there is very limited communication - to the rest of us - in how they are supposed to be pronounced"? A guide for the Squamish orthography written in English obviously exists; it's right there on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Also, what's your basis for your statement that "there is limited homogenization between tribes"? You give one example of a language with multiple different writing systems; is that the only one, or are there several indigenous languages with multiple writing systems? You are aware, of course, that Canada has many different indigenous languages, and it wouldn't make sense to try to unify or homogenize the writing systems for different languages.

Comment: @DavidHammen you can see English's spelling-anarchism as a nice thing or as a deficiency. At any rate, one thing does often rub people from other countries the wrong way is when English speakers approach their local names by just 1. dropping any diacritics as if they were only meaningless ornaments 2. picking some pronunciation of this ASCII-form as if it was an English word. The result often sounds nothing like the word in its native language, even when the original pronunciation wouldn't be difficult at all for an English speaker if only they had bothered to look it up.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Given that my last name should be Njállssen (or maybe Neilsen or Neilson or maybe even an overly anglicized Nelson) rather than Hammen, I agree with your sentiment.  Yet another Ellis Island mess-up. Note that I used "nice" in my comment in sarcastic quotes.

Comment: @DavidHammen Re. the "niceness":  *"Should I record this, for the record?", he mused*.

Comment: @vsz Don't be so sure about [expectations](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/heiltsuk-nation-indigenous-name-bc-government-identification-1.6093186).  Second, if the spelling is too exotic, people will stick to the English names.  *Haida Gwaii* is a big improvement over *Queen Charlotte* and so is *Salish Sea* over *Georgia Straight*.  It is more respectful, and relevant, than dotting the place with the names of old, dead, white, male English lords.  *But the use of those names also wouldn't have taken off if spelled in a fashion no one understood*.  Whistler will remain Whistler

Comment: The two examples you posted don't seem to be "new symbols that are being made up as they go". They use glyphs from the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) that was invented over a hundred years ago. It seems to me like those names are from languages without a script (or at least not with one that has a generally accepted way to transliterate to English), so they use IPA to represent the pronounciation as well as possible.

Comment: @Philipp Not quite. The underbar and acute accent don't represent their IPA value.

Comment: @Philipp thanks, updated answer, hadn't noticed that, can't say I've ever spent any time looking at the IPA.